# Having trouble with Time Objects for a Dygraph Output

Tags: r, excel, csv

I am writing a script for a Shiny App that will allow my users to upload their own CSV files (all the files that anyone would upload are similar to the sample dataset found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzg7bDcyZobbc1Zoc0VoN3ZzSmM).  The Shiny app should then allow the user to select one of the headers with a SelectInput and then graph it in a Dygraph output.  The issue that I am running into is the correct way of converting the Time object to the appropriate format to create the Dygraph output.

Right now, I am receiving the error:

```
Error in lapply(X = x, FUN = "[", ..., drop = drop) : 
  argument is missing, with no default
```

The thing is, when I manually modify the Time column **inside Excel** to be of the format: `h:mm:ss`, it works.  I don't want to have to ask my users to modify the .csv in Excel before uploading it.

## server.R

```
library(xts)
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
# Upload the CSV File 
  uploadedFile1 <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file1, FALSE)) # This is like a better "if (is.null(input$file1)) return(NULL)"
    uf1 <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    uf2$Time <- strptime(uf2$Time, format= "%H:%M:%S")
  })

  uploadedFile2 <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file2, FALSE)) # This is like a better "if (is.null(input$file2)) return(NULL)"
    uf2 <- read.csv(input$file2$datapath, stringsAsFactors=F)
    uf2$Time <- strptime(uf2$Time, format= "%H:%M:%S")

  })

  observeEvent(uploadedFile1(), {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels1', choices = names(uploadedFile1()))
  })
  observeEvent(uploadedFile2(), {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels2', choices = names(uploadedFile2()))
  })

  output$graph <- renderDygraph({


    # Clean up the loaded CSV File, convert Time column to a Time Object for Dygraph.
    uploadedFile1 <- uploadedFile1()
    uploadedFile2 <- uploadedFile2()
    uploadedFile1$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile1$Time,"%H:%M:%S"))
    uploadedFile2$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile2$Time,"%H:%M:%S"))

    uploadedFile1$ctime <- strptime(paste(uploadedFile1$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    uploadedFile2$ctime <- strptime(paste(uploadedFile2$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    # Update the SelectInput and store the value in component5 to be used in the graph.
    selectedInput1 <- input$uploadChannels1
    selectedInput2 <- input$uploadChannels2
    component5 <- uploadedFile1[, selectedInput1]
    component6 <- uploadedFile2[, selectedInput2]
    cbinded <- cbind(component5, component6)

        xts(cbinded, uploadedFile1$Time, uploadedFile2$Time)  %>% 
      dygraph()

    })

})
```

## ui.R

```
library(xts)
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Data Graph",
tabPanel("Upload a CSV File:",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                                    accept=c('text/csv', 
                                             'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                             '.csv')),
                          selectInput("uploadChannels1", label = "Choose a Temp. Rise Location",
                                      choices = NULL),
                          fileInput('file2', 'Choose CSV File',
                                    accept=c('text/csv', 
                                             'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                             '.csv')),
                          selectInput("uploadChannels2", label = "Choose a Temp. Rise Location",
                                      choices = NULL),
                          tags$hr(),
                          checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                          radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                       c(Comma=',',
                                         Semicolon=';',
                                         Tab='\t'),
                                       ',')

                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                              dygraphOutput('graph')
                        ))



                        )

                               )))
```

Comment: try in code to replace uploadedFile1$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile1$Time,"%H:%M:%S")) by uploadedFile1$Time <- as.POSIXlt(uploadedFile1$Time,"%H:%M:%S") and  uploadedFile1$ctime <- strptime(paste(uploadedFile1$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") by uploadedFile1$ctime <- strptime(uploadedFile1$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Comment: I received the following error: Error in as.POSIXlt.default(uploadedFile1$Time, "%H:%M:%S") : 
  do not know how to convert 'uploadedFile1$Time' to class “POSIXlt”

Comment: I forgot in your file min are followed by "." try this instead format="%H:%M.%S"

Comment: I changed the colon to a period and I still received the same error..

Comment: change colon to a period needs only to be done in the first one uploadedFile1$Time <- as.POSIXlt(uploadedFile1$Time,"%H:%M.%S") and the second replacement stay the same uploadedFile1$ctime <- strptime(uploadedFile1$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Comment: I'm unfortunately getting the same error: do not know how to convert 'uploadedFile1$Time' to class “POSIXlt”

Comment: I do it manually so I know it's working, but you go through shiny so we don't know exactly the structure and class of uploadedFile1$Time...but we have through this before a few weeks ago have we?

Comment: I also noticed that uploadedFile1$Time is pull out of uploadedFile1()

Comment: Yes, so am I calling the output from uploadedFile1() correctly?

Comment: no you did it right, but I just wondering what's the structure of Time (probably not like in your csv file); you need to look into this

Comment: The time is being read in as `h:mm.s` instead of `h:mm:s`.  Is this a problem?

Comment: yes! because you will have to your format your Time in your POSIXlt() accordingly

Comment: My issue is that I don't know what to put into the uploadedFile1 function after I read the csv in.  Whatever I do changes all the values in the Time column to NA.

Comment: I don't think you should set the time format in uploadedFile1 <- reactive({}), only in uploadedFile2$ctime

Comment: Damn... I get the error: Error in as.POSIXlt.character(uploadedFile1$Time, "%H:%M.%S") : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: you should start from the beginning, a very simple app with only your plot and then add gradually new stuff

Comment: I think I found my issue.  The `%H` can only take a number from `0-23`, and when the file is being uploaded to R, the item in the %H position is `40`.  I checked this by changing %H to %M.  But this obviously doesn't work, because it resets once the second %M goes past 59 and I don't see the full plot.  Any ideas on how to get around this in R?

Comment: funny thing is I am also dealing an excel issue of my own. We should avoid using Excel as much as we can. Can you bypass using Excel?